# All over the world news api for android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, api

I'm making an application which I want to have the latest news for several countries and regions all over the world, the thing is I don't know if there's an api to get news from several places or if I have to inquire an api for each country I want to get the news from and then support said api in my app.

Question: is there any api that gives me news from all over the world or do I have to get an api for each country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the RSS from Google News, you can find it at the bottom of [their news page](https://news.google.com/nwshp?edchanged=1&ned=us), and you can change the country (and language) to any of the countries they provide. The RSS provides images and all.

Example RSS for US news:
http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&hl=en&output=rss

Answer (score 1):

http://api.breakingnews.com/api/v1/item/?format=json

This will give you news from around the world in Json format and then you will just need to parse. I am not sure if they have any way to set specifics as I have not had time to implement this api myself but will be over the next month or so.

I believe that this is from NBC and that the articles seen in this api are featured in their breaking news app on ios.

Another is https://code.google.com/p/feedzilla-api/wiki/RestApi which allows you to specify cultures and more. Again I haven't worked with these as of yet. If you do please let us know that what you think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, breaking news looks good but i'm going to use google news as it fits more my needs.